# Android: How to call functions in a Android service repetitively?

Tags: android, service

I have created a Android service where I am finding out the process which are in Error state and the usage stats of app from UsageStatManager. When I run this service then it executes the methods in it once and I want to do a periodic check of the process in error state and the usage stats of apps.

One way I thought of was to implement a while loop with a Thread.sleep() for the time I would like to check my statistics but wondering if there is any other way of doing this in a much better way as placing a while loop may use CPU consumption. Any ideas would be helpfull.

My code:

```
public class Senddata_1 extends Service {

private String ip = "85.228.204.209";
private int port = 5000;
String message;
String file;
String TAG = "Senddata_1";

private static final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("M-d-yyyy HH:mm:ss");

public void find_out_process_in_error_state(){

    /*Some code to find out process in error state*/
    return;
}

private UsageStatsManager getUsageStatsManager(Context context){
    UsageStatsManager usm = (UsageStatsManager) context.getSystemService("usagestats");
    return usm;
}

public List<UsageStats> getUsageStatsList(Context context){


    List<UsageStats> usageStatsList = usm.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_DAILY,startTime,endTime);
    return usageStatsList;
}

public void printUsageStats(List<UsageStats> usageStatsList){

}


@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Log.e(TAG, "Inside service Senddata_1");


    find_out_process_in_error_state();
    printUsageStats(getUsageStatsList(Senddata_1.this));

    new Thread(new Senddata_1.ClientSend()).start();

}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    return START_STICKY;
}


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
//        return;
}

public class ClientSend implements Runnable {

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

you can use Timer and in there set time to start service and run function

```
Timer timer = new Timer(); 
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            //start service here

        }
    }, 0, mTimeRate);
```

mTimeRate will be in milliseconds